# Setting WPF Control from WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, xaml

I am trying to set the name (textbox) value using WCF Service. I am hosting service in WPF application. I used the MVVM Model initially to set textbox value from the MainWindow.cs and it worked. But then I made some properties static in order to access the same through the service contract. It still seems to setting the property of Model attribute but not changing value in the text box. Can anyone please guide me?

**Model.cs**

```
 public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        MessageBox.Show(field.ToString());

        return true;
    }

    // props
    private static string testname;
    public  static string TestName
    {
        get { return testname; }
        set {
            Model m = new Model();
            m.SetField(ref testname, value, "TestName");
        }
    }    


}
```

WCF **InameService.cs**

```
 public class nameService : InameService
{
    public void setMyName(string name)
    {
        Model.TestName = name;

    }


}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid Name="GridName">

    <TextBox Name="TextName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="193,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TestName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(nameService));
        InitializeComponent();
        host.Open();

        Model s = new Model();
        //this.DataContext = s.NameValue.TestName;
        Model.TestName = "Alicia";
        this.TextName.DataContext = s;

    }
}
```

Comment: First off, don't think that you can just make any property static and expect it to still work. It won't.

Comment: if I am making that public then I can't set the value through Service Operation Contract. I can only get values from service contract by using any trigger like button click but can't set values using WCF client which I need to.

Comment: That's part of your problem. You make them static and create new instances and set values on those. But that doesn't change any values on the original model instance you created.  Instead, make a static singleton of your **non-static** model, and modify that from your WCF code.

Comment: I changed my ViewModel to singleton class and now I am accessing it in MainWindow.xaml.cs using following  try
            {
                ViewModel s = ViewModel.Instance;
                this.DataContext = s.NameValue.TestName;
                s.NameValue.TestName = "Alicia";
                this.TextName.DataContext = s;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + e.Message);
            }

Comment: It is giving me error "object reference not set to instance of an object" though through call trace I can see that it is reaching to the point where I am creating single instance of the ViewModel. 
              if (instance == null)
             {
                  lock (_mutex)
                  {
                       if (instance == null)
                       {
                         instance = new ViewModel();
                         
                       }
                  }
              }
   
              return instance;
           }
       }

Comment: You aren't yet qualified or educated enough in programming and WPF to use this website. Your question is off topic because you don't have a minimal understanding of your own code. This website is *not* here to teach users anything... we're here to help developers with specific programming problems. As such, I am voting to close this question for being too broad in scope. You can find out more in the Stack Overflow [Help Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Is there something wrong in the post. Should we stop trying if we are stucking somewhere?  I have used MVVM in WPF earlier but this is my first time to get the value through WCF into the the control. previously I was using it to provide information to other applications. I have fixed the errors mentioned in previous posts. I hope I will get there. And there must be someone who can help!

Comment: And I did that. Thanks to Nathan A for clues and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Nathan for help. Following is the answer:

I changed the ViewModel to Singleton Class and also instantiated the composite Model object while creating the instance.

`class ViewModel
    {
        private static volatile ViewModel instance;
        private static object _mutex = new object();

```
    private ViewModel() { }


    private  Model model;        

    public  Model NameValue
    {
        get { return model; }
        set { model = value; }
    }        


    public static ViewModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (_mutex)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new ViewModel();
                        instance.model = new Model();
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}`
```

then changed the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
try
        {
            ViewModel s = ViewModel.Instance;

            s.NameValue.TestName = "Alicia";
            this.DataContext = s;
            this.TextName.DataContext = s;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + e.Message);
        }
```

Similar changes was done in the Service Contract Class. I hope this will help some one trying to get the value in

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static properties as you can't bind to them. Use a static object instead or pass the Model object to the service for example in the constructor and use that instance for updates.

```
public class nameService : InameService
{

    private Model model; 

    public nameService(Model m) 
    {
       model = m;
    }

    public void setMyName(string name)
    {
        model.TestName = name;
    }
}

public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        MessageBox.Show(field.ToString());

        return true;
    }

    // props
    private string testname;
    public  string TestName
    {
        get { return testname; }
        set {
            Model m = new Model();
            m.SetField(ref testname, value, "TestName");
        }
    }    
}
```